# Unity - UI AND PARTICLES

Tags: unity-game-engine, text, particles

I have a scene which has 3d particles. It also has ui elements. Unfortunately the particles get in the way of the text. Is there a way that the text can be unaffected by the particle effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution one: Rendering UI and particle with different cameras. You can use different layers for that.

Solution two: Assign different sorting layers to particle system and canvas.